# How to use Google cloud Firestore Emulator for Java in Spring boot Application project

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

i tried to connect firestore emulator to spring boot application. but it is not working.

firestore emulator implementation [firestore implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqVBw.png).

firestore start. [firestore start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7aFf.png)

Comment: Hi Prajwal, this is your first question. Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow has content guidelines. It's better to include the code directly in the question instead of using external pictures.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Firebase, Firestore, and Functions Emulator in Quarkus application, and it is functioning properly. The setup should be similar in Spring Boot.

Here is the code to initialize the Firebase App. The section with the owner token is crucial, and it was challenging to locate. Without it, authentication with emulator tokens is not possible.

```
  private static FirebaseApp getEmulatorFirebaseApp() {
    var credentials = GoogleCredentials.create(new AccessToken(
        "owner",
        Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().plusYears(1).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())));
    var options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
        .setCredentials(credentials)
        .build();
    return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options,
        "app_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
  }
```

- Start the emulator from the command line

```
firebase emulators:start 2>&1 \
        --project "$firebase_project_id" \
        --only auth,database,firestore,functions \
        --import /data
```

- Set emulator variables.

To start the Spring Boot applications with the required environment variables, please ensure that the ports are correct.

```
FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:18084
GCLOUD_PROJECT=my-project
FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:19199
```